# Can't setup modules for requests and runtime - no module named requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting the following error message when trying to use `requests`:

```
Error processing line 3 of C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\Python\lib\site-packages\pygtk.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\Python\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named runtime

Remainder of file ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ws1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are requests and runtime installed?

```
pip install runtime
pip install requests
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer